# Fork reading multiple files and write them to single output file

Tags: c, fork

I want to read from multiple files and write them into single file using fork(). I have 3 child processes each of them seperately read 3 input files and I want to write contents of these files into single output file in parent process.
For example I have 3 `txt` files which are read in child processes:

```
sample1.txt => 1 2 3
sample2.txt => 4 5 6
sample3.txt => 7 8 9
```

I want to write them to single **output.txt** in parent process as shown in below:

`1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`

I cannot get desired output file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int status = 0;
FILE *fptr[3];
char fn[100];
char output[100];
int n = 0;
int i = 0;

int
main()
{
    for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
        if (fork() == 0) {
            sprintf(fn, "sample%d.txt", (k + 1));

            fptr[k] = fopen(fn, "r");

            while (fscanf(fptr[k], "%d", &output[i]) == 1) {
                n++;
                i++;
            }

            for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                fscanf(fptr[k], "%d", &output[i]);
            }
        }
        else {
            wait(&status);
            FILE *fp;

            fp = fopen("output.txt", "w+");
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                fprintf(fp, "%d ", output[i]);
            }
        }

        printf("Bye\n");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

---

Are there any better ways I missed?

Comment: You didn't show the format of the data in the files. It appears to be some numbers that you decode with `fscanf`. Compile with `-Wall` to see that `output` should be `int` and _not_ `char`. Doing that is _slow_. Having a fixed size buffer doesn't scale as a solution. And, it can _not_ work at all because `output` is _not_ shared between child and parent. You would be better off with a `pipe` and child does `fread` on input file, `fwrite` to pipe. Parent does `fread` on pipe and does `fwrite` to output file.

Comment: You don't check that all the input function calls work — this is the first thing you must do when things don't work as expected.  Similarly with most system calls. 
 Your files contain letters — what do you think `fscanf()` is going to do when you read a file using `%d`?  You are reading into a char array with `%d` too — that's not happy.  How do you think the information gets back to the parent process?  Remember, they are separate processes — changes made by the child aren't visible in the parent and vice versa.

Comment: You will either need to set up shared memory or use pipes for the children to write back to the parent, or otherwise set up some form of IPC — inter-process communication.  Because you are using `fork()` rather than `pthread_create()`, this is not multi-threading; it is multi-processing.

Comment: Rather then needing to pipe whatever you read in the children to the parent for the parent to then write to the file, you could `fork()` and then use `execvp()` (or another function in that family) to call a shell command to append each target file to the destination file.

Comment: I first tried with integer numbers so I put %d. I have 1 2 3 for first , 4 5 6 for second and 7 8 9 for third

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any better ways I missed?

Instead of using multiple processes, one could use multiple threads (lightweight processes).
Threads share the memory space of the parent process, child processes created via `fork` are processes themselves and do run in separate memory spaces. For inter-process communication ([IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)) one has to use either shared memory objects, pipes or other forms of data exchange.

An example using multiple threads and a barrier object:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

//number of total threads (input files)
#define NUM_THREADS 4

//thread data passed to each thread
struct thread_param {
    pthread_t handle;
    int       id;
    char*     content;
    size_t    content_size;
};

//global vars
static struct thread_param params[NUM_THREADS];
static pthread_barrier_t barrier;

//thread starting function
//arg is a pointer to struct thread_param
void* run(void *arg)
{
    //cast to proper data type
    struct thread_param *param = (struct thread_param*) arg;

    //generate filename
    char filename[100];
    snprintf(filename, 100, "sample%d.txt", (param->id + 1));

    //read file into buffer
    FILE *in = fopen(filename, "r");
    param->content_size = getdelim(&param->content, &param->content_size, EOF, in);
    fclose(in);

    //the last arriving thread does the multiplexing and cleanup
    if (pthread_barrier_wait(&barrier) == PTHREAD_BARRIER_SERIAL_THREAD) 
    {
        FILE *out = fopen("output.txt", "w+");
        for (int i=0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i)
        {
            //write in proper order
            fwrite(params[i].content, params[i].content_size, 1, out);
            //free content
            free(params[i].content);
        }
        fclose(out);
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    //initialize barrier with the number of threads
    pthread_barrier_init(&barrier, NULL, NUM_THREADS);

    //for each thread
    for (int i=0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i)
    {
        //prepare thread data
        params[i].id = i;
        params[i].content = NULL;
        params[i].content_size = 0;

        //create thread and invoke starting function with the proper data
        pthread_create(&params[i].handle, NULL, run, &params[i]);
    }

    //for each thread
    for (int i=0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i) 
    {
        //join the thread, therefore cleanup of thread resources
        pthread_join(params[i].handle, NULL);
    }

    pthread_barrier_destroy(&barrier);
}
```

Compile with gcc:

```
gcc -Wall -pthread -o main main.c
```

**References:**

- [getdelim](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getdelim)
- [pthread_barrier_init / -destroy](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_barrier_init)
- [pthread_barrier_wait](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_barrier_wait)
- [pthread_create](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_create)
- [pthread_join](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_join)